# Jasypt encrypted String not being able to decrypt on another machine

Tags: java, encryption, salt, jasypt

Our security department wants us to use 256-bit encryption to encrypt SSN, Names of Users etc, so we decided to go with JASYPT with the sample code below:

```
encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
encryptor.setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC");
encryptor.setPassword(OUR_KEY)
encryptor.encrypt("TEXT TO ECNCRYPT")
```

The problem we noticed is when our application creates an encrypted record from our local machine, the application on the app-dev server cannot decrypt it and vice versa even though the key is same. It seems like JASYPT is adding some machine specific information in the salt (Mac address etc).

Even using `FixedStringSaltGenerator` or `ZeroSaltGenerator` does not help. This creates a problem for us because if we ever migrated our production server to another machine, or refreshed pre-prod data with the prod data, we may need a couple of million years to recover the information.

The security department wants us to use a well know library and not brew an in-house solution. Can someone please throw some light on this issue on how we can generate encrypted string that can be decrypted across different machines using jasypt 256 bit encryption, or when we refresh pre-prod database with prod data, how we would be able to recover names etc that were encrypted through a different server?

Any useful insights will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do your machines have different endianness? Verify that the encrypted byte array on machine1 is the same as the encrypted byte array on machine2; you may need to use something like a [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) to get them to match.

Comment: "*we may need a couple of million years to recover the information*" > classic... got a chuckle from me :-)

Comment: Thanks O'Pootertoot. Half of the problem is solved. Our local env is windows which is little endian, and servers are solaris which is big endian. We confirmed that we can encrypt/decrypt data across multiple windows machines or our dev and test servers, but it doesn't work when data is encrypted on windows and decrypted on the server. I wonder if Jasypt provides a way to address this issue.

Comment: Where does the password OUR_KEY come from ? Does both environments run with the same code pages ? Does OUR_KEY.getBytes() give the same value in bot environments ?

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen For testing purpose, I have hardcoded the key in the code. I checked key.getBytes(). The value is different on windows and Solaris unless you set it as key.getBytes("UTF-8"); however, in StandardPBEStringEncryptor class there doesn't seem to be a way to set it up. Also on its [API page](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEStringEncryptor.html#setConfig(org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.PBEConfig), it says "This class avoids byte-conversion problems related to the fact of different platforms having different default charsets."

Answer (score 1):

your key might be containing some special characters which shell substitute with something else.
do a echo "yourkey" > file
and check the content of this file. 
then use this content as a key to decrypt; it should be able to decrypt the encrypted string.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old question but I recently experienced this issue and the resolution for me had nothing to do with the differences in machine operating system endianness.

It had to do with a character in the password itself, the dollar sign character ($), that was somehow considered to be a special character in Linux vs not being considered special in Windows. So everything worked fine encrypting the values in Windows, but when I swapped over to Linux and tried to decrypt the values with the same password using the jasypt command line decrypt.sh script, I got the error message "Operation not possible (Bad input or parameters)" and noticed that the password in the jasypt decrypt output arguments list was different than the one I had typed in (the script apparently chopped off the part of the password from the special character until the end of the password string).

Anyway, my solution was to change the password to not use a special character and then it worked. Hope this helps some poor soul who happens to run across this same issue in future, because I wasted 2 days on it.

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes instead of double quotes to wrap your input string. This solution worked when i had a issue with encryption and decryption of string with $.

Comment: Single Quotes will take character! How will you keep a String while enc/dec? For Sting you can not avoid using " "